# Prepend "http://www" to data-src through jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on building a basic web scraper and I would like to prepend URL domain names to my image results. Here is the code I have so far:

```
function pageFunction(context) {
    var $ = context.jQuery;
    var results = [];
    $('.product').each(function() {
        results.push({
            title: $(this).find('.plp-product-anchor').attr('title'),
            link: $(this).find('.plp-product-anchor').attr('href'),
            price: $(this).find('span[itemprop="price"]').text(),
            image: $(this).find('.plp-product-anchor img').attr('data-src'),
        });
    });
    return results;
}
```

Everything works fine so far but the image results only bring back the file path `(/wcsstore/CatalogAssetStore/Attachment/images/products/golf/P130313/1-t.jpg)` and leaves off the protocol and domain name.

I would like to return results that prepends that info to the link looks like so **http://www.tgw.com**/wcsstore/CatalogAssetStore/Attachment/images/products/golf/P130313/1-t.jpg)

Comment: Can you do Image: window.location.hostname + $(this).find....

Comment: Brilliant! That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Added the comment to your function.
```

```js
function pageFunction(context) {
    var $ = context.jQuery;
    var results = [];
    $('.product').each(function() {
        results.push({
            title: $(this).find('.plp-product-anchor').attr('title'),
            link: $(this).find('.plp-product-anchor').attr('href'),
            price: $(this).find('span[itemprop="price"]').text(),
            image: window.location.hostname + $(this).find('.plp-product-anchor img').attr('data-src'),
        });
    });
    return results;
}
```

Comment: `.attr('data-src')` can be replaced with `.data('src')`. see https://devdocs.io/jquery/data